# Installs for Google play & other app stores

Tags: google-play-store, amazon-appstore

A user can download the android app from any where - Google play, Amazon app store, Opera app store, Samsung app store..

Some of the android apps can also be ported into other OS providing access to android apps, like Kindle Fire OS, Blackberry OS, Nokia X.

Do install numbers seen in Google play developer statistics include installs from other app stores like amazon, opera, Samsung etc.,?

How about android apps that can be installed non-android devices as stated above?

Comment: You will have to ask Google how they compute the statistics. Overall, this question is off-topic here because it is about publishing of apps.

Answer (score 1):

The app stores you mention are different from each other. So, they maintain separate / different statistics.